# Using aes() to recolor only one line in a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, legend

I have a set of data that looks like this:

```
Year Region       Yield
2009 northeast    9.1
2009 northwest    8
2009 yorkshire    7.8
2009 eastmidlands 8.1
2009 westmidlands 7.9
...
2016 Average      8.0
2017 Average      8.1
2018 Average      7.4
```

The data runs from 2009 to 2018. At the bottom of the data there are a bunch of averages for each of the years. I want to plot the data with the following code but I want to change the aestetic of the average line only (preferably to a `size=2, linetipe=dashed, color="blue"`).

```
viz1 <- ggplot(vizdata, aes(x=Year,y=Yield)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=Year,y=Yield, color = Region),size=1) +
  geom_point(aes(color=Region),size = 2) +
  labs(title = "Yield for Winter Wheat", subtitle = "Winter wheat yield throughout the UK between 2009 and 2018", y = "Yield  [t/ha]") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(2009, 2018, 1))
```

[image: Plot resulting from the ggplot()]

I have also tried separating out the average data and plotting it as its own `geom_line`, but then the new line doesn't seem to show up on the legend at all.

Any chance you could help?

Answer (score 0):

Using some summary gapminder data on mean life expectancy by world regions as example data this could be achieved like so.

Basic idea is to use named vectors to specify the values for the aes which can then be used via `scale_xxx_manual` to set the `color`, `linetype` and `size` of the lines:

```r
library(ggplot2)

vizdata <- structure(list(year = c(
  2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L,
  2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L,
  2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L,
  2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L
), region = c(
  "Africa",
  "Americas", "Asia", "Europe", "Africa", "Americas", "Asia", "Europe",
  "Africa", "Americas", "Asia", "Europe", "Africa", "Americas",
  "Asia", "Europe", "Africa", "Americas", "Asia", "Europe", "Africa",
  "Americas", "Asia", "Europe", "World", "World", "World", "World",
  "World", "World"
), life_exp = c(
  61.0055555555556, 73.3484848484848,
  71.9498113207547, 77.4325581395349, 61.1925925925926, 74.4, 72.1739622641509,
  77.746511627907, 61.9648148148148, 74.5515151515151, 72.3358490566038,
  78, 62.3611111111111, 74.6666666666667, 72.5845283018868, 78.2348837209302,
  62.5907407407407, 74.8515151515151, 72.708679245283, 78.3906976744186,
  63.0648148148148, 75.0181818181818, 72.8515094339623, 78.5279069767442,
  70.2608743169399, 70.6443715846995, 71.0060109289617, 71.2709289617486,
  71.4445901639344, 71.6881420765027
)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c(
  "tbl_df",
  "tbl", "data.frame"
))

names_regions <- setdiff(unique(vizdata$region), "World")
n_regions <- length(names_regions)

cols <- c(World = "blue", setNames(scales::hue_pal()(n_regions), names_regions))
ltys <- c(World = "dashed", setNames(rep("solid", n_regions), names_regions))
sizes <- c(World = 2, setNames(rep(1, n_regions), names_regions))

viz1 <- ggplot(vizdata, aes(x=year,y=life_exp)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = region, linetype = region, size = region)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = region),size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = cols) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = ltys) +
  scale_size_manual(values = sizes) +
  labs(title = "Yield for Winter Wheat", subtitle = "Winter wheat yield throughout the UK between 2009 and 2018", y = "Yield  [t/ha]") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(2009, 2018, 1))
viz1
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>